# Объявление переменных Smarty

Tags: php, переменные, smarty

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как уже в самом файле *.tpl объявить переменную и присвоить ей значение. Мне нужно что-то типа того:

```
{if ($data.rating >= 600)}
  {$a='Подходит!'}
{/if}
```

Comment: @Sexy Girl, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Smarty 2](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.assign)
- [Smarty 3](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)

Вот:

```
{if ($data.rating >= 600)}
    {assign var="a" value="Подходит"}
{/if}
```

Comment: метод с `{assign var="variable" value="12345"}`, он же `{$variable="12345"}` работает в пределах одного объекта **smarty** и не позволяет объявлять для некоторых **include** конструкций, реализующих полное построение html-страницы ... было бы интересно узнать способ, как объявить переменную глобально?

Comment: @red_python, перенёс из ответа в комментарий ваш вопрос. Но вряд ли автор ответа вам ответит - его уже 2 года на сайте не было. Лучше задайте отдельный новый вопрос.